# Getting Docker linked containers localhost pointing to host localhost

Tags: php, networking, docker, dockerfile, hosts

So on my host environment I have this tomcat service running on port 10000 so I can access the office internal services.

I have a windows hosts entry:

`localhost developer.mycompany.com`

So I can access the endpoint `developer.mycompany.com:10000/some/url` and if successful return a json response.

I also have a Docker compose file that has spun up nginx and php-fpm containers and linked them to run a linux based PHP development environment.

What I am trying to achieve is to make the docker container(s) aware of the `developer.mycomoany.com` host entry. So when my PHP code on my linke containers sends a POST request to `http://developer.mycompany.com:10000/some/url`it knows about the host entry and is able to hit that end point.

I have tried the config `net=host` but that doesn't work with linked containers.

PHP app error message:

> {"result":{"success":false,"message":"Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known\n[file] /srv/http/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php\n[line] 282\n[message] fopen(http://developer.mycompany.com:10000/app/register): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known\n[file] /srv/http/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php\n[line] 282"}}

How do I enable my PHP app on my linked containers to talk to the host `developer.mycompany.com` (localhost) entry?

Here is my docker-compose:

```
app:
  image: linxlad/docker-php-fpm
  tty: true
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  volumes:
   - ./logs/php-fpm:/var/log/php-fpm
   - ~/Development/Apps/php-hello-world:/srv/http
web:
  image: linxlad/docker-nginx
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - ./conf/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
   - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
   - ~/Development/Apps/php-hello-world:/srv/http
  links:
   - app
```

**Edits:**

Her is my ifconfig output from docker machine.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I post my docker composer file so do you mean `app:host.name` and that will reference the host /etc/hosts entry?

Comment: This host name is really a service running the host environment. Can my linked containers talk to my host environment localhost/127.0.0.1? Sorry not great with networks. Wouldn't I need to add a hosts entry in my containers along the lines of `<host env IP address> developer.mycompany.com`?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'd misunderstood. Going to drop my comments.

Comment: Would adding this `extra_hosts: - "developer.mycompany.com:<host env IP address>"` to the docker compose file would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the IP of my docker machine and used that in my hosts nginx proxy config like such which then redirected it to the nginx location config in my docker container.

Host nginx:

```
location /apps/myapp/appversion {
    proxy_pass   http://192.168.99.100:8080;
}
```

Docker Nginx container config:

```
location /apps/myapp/appversion {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
    }
}
```